# Shopify cart.js (rivets version) removing multiple products instead of one at a time

Tags: shopify, cart, rivets

```html
<div rv-data-cart-update-id="item.id" rv-data-cart-update="item.quantity | minus 1" style="position: absolute; top: -2px; right: 4px; cursor: pointer;" data-cart-update-id="12541069361194" data-cart-update="3">
<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2556/0186/files/180424_cross_10x10.png?7401277007178548701" alt="">
</div>
```

I have a thumbnail displaying the quatity of a products, and when the cross is pressed it should remove one item only, and display 3 (data-cart-update="3") but it removes all bar one.

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps rendering your code incorrectly in your question, although who knows with SO. If you were thinking this code made sense, it does not. Try using Liquid in your code.

Your line: rv-data-cart-update="item.quantity | minus 1"

Try: rv-data-cart-update="{{item.quantity | minus 1}}"